# Have UK exports (goods and services) to Ireland declined in value since 2011?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, balance-of-trade, balance-of-payments

Where can I find the relevant Office Of National Statistics data on UK exports to Ireland? I want to know if the value of UK exports to Ireland has declined since 2011 and if so, does anyone know why that might be? I understand the reasons that UK market share in Ireland has decreased, but I'm in interested in why the total value may have decreased (or not). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [ONS Balance of Payments Pink Book](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/nationalaccounts/balanceofpayments/datasets/pinkbook) gives the following figures for UK exports to Ireland (£million).  The figures in Euros would be different, as would Irish reporting of the numbers, but there seems to have been a sharp drop in services exports from 2012 to 2013.

2016 data is due to be published in October 2017, though trade in goods numbers may already be available

```
 £m     Goods Services  Both
CDID    QDJJ    FYVJ    LGIA
2011    18223   11475   29698
2012    17234   11615   28849
2013    18592    8780   27372
2014    18104    9288   27392
2015    16764    9321   26085
```

Answer (score 0):

These are values in million **US$**, from [UN Comtrade](https://comtrade.un.org/data/) database:

[image]

Data of graph is:

```
Year    Goods   Services
1993    10254   -
1994    10201   -
1995    12012   -
1996    13422   -
1997    15607   -
1998    16116   -
1999    17423   -
2000    19523   4180
2001    20568   4903
2002    23928   6861
2003    21114   9383
2004    26186   10840
2005    29982   10965
2006    32227   12574
2007    35877   15559
2008    34916   13744
2009    24448   12811
2010    25676   15910
2011    27988   18496
2012    25521   18374
2013    28376   13601
2014    29319   15628
2015    25499   -
2016    23154   -
```

Although this is not a primary source (as ONS), they have the potential benefit of being comparable across countries (all in USD). The drawback is that they are not in GBP. This only matter is the GBP/USD has varied considerable over time, which it has:

[image]

You can always reconvert them into GBP, using for example [this data](http://www.macrotrends.net/2549/pound-dollar-exchange-rate-historical-chart).